# How to assign regex to variable for later use on a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, oop

I currently have this:

```
var input = "some input";
var firstRegex = input.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
var secondRegex = /ee/.test(input);
```

So if the input variable is undefined, both regex's will stop the code from compiling in the browser.

Is there a way to assign the regex's to variables so that they can later be called on input?

For example, inside an object:

```
var checkStrings = {

 firstRegex : match(/[aeiou]/gi),
 secondRegex : /ee/,

}

// call on input
 checkStrings.firstRegex(input);
```

Comment: What about just `/[aeiou]/gi` instead of `match(/[aeiou]/gi)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use predicates:

```
var checkStrings = {
    checkFirstRegex = function(x) { 
        return x.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
    },
    checkSecondRegex = function(x) {
        return /ee/.test(x);
    }
};

// call on input
checkStrings.firstRegex(input);
```

With the ES6 arrow functions it becomes even shorter:

```
var checkStrings = {
    checkFirstRegex = x=> x.match(/[aeiou]/gi),
    checkSecondRegex = x => /ee/.test(x)
};
```

Answer (score 5):

This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) from Mozilla goes into a little more detail about the RegExp object in js, but if you want to simply assign a regexp to a variable, you can just do:

```
var firstRegex = new RegExp(/[aeiou]/gi);
var secondRegex = new RegExp(/ee/);
```

Then you would call them the same way you do now.

```
if (input) {
    var matches = input.match(firstRegex);
    var passedTest = secondRegex.test(input);
}
```

You could obviously do this much easier in an object as @IIya suggested, but I thought I'd add some info about the RegExp object in js.